# Get last_insert_id for INSERT DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement when there is no update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database that needs to handle 2 special scenarios in case of duplicate key. In each case I need to obtain the unique id of the row whether there is duplicate record or not

**Scenario #1** the record_count field has to be incremented by 1. So the mysql syntax looks like this

```
 INSERT INTO (id, value, record_count) VALUES ('foo','bar', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE record_count=record_count+1
```

In this case `$mysqli->insert_id` method gives me correct value whether it is a new record or a duplicate record. Everything is good.

**Scenario #2** the `record_count` field does not need to be incremented. I tried following 3 statements

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO (id, value, record_count) VALUES ('foo','bar', 1)

INSERT INTO (id, value, record_count) VALUES ('foo','bar', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE record_count=record_count

INSERT INTO (id, value, record_count) VALUES ('foo','bar', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE record_count=record_count+1-1
```

But in each case `$mysqli->insert_id` is yielding me 0 because I am not updating or inserting anything. I thought I could fool it by adding and subtracting 1 but no luck.

What is the workaround? I really do not want to use a `SELECT` statement (I am sending hundreds of queries per minute and I really do not want to increase the system load)

Comment: What is your table's Primary key? since you are using PHP, you can calculate the values to insert AFTER you get values using php

Comment: Add a `TIMESTAMP` column that updates?

Answer (score 0):

Since, I have not received any answers, here is what I am doing.

I created another dummy column which stores md5 hash. When I don't want to update the record_count, I update the dummy column so I can get the id of the column.

As @miken32 suggested, I can use a timestamp column as well (which might be more efficient).

Still looking for a better answer, if it exists.

Comment: Simply select using the values you passed to the query which hit the unique constraint? Why complicate? If the `last_insert_id` gives you back 0, select using those values you tried to insert. Create a simple wrapper around those and voila, job done, no need to alter table or use timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql_insert_id() documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-insert-id.html) details all the cases, but explicitly details `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as only updating when there is an actual change to the database.

So, to get an insert id out of MySQL, you have to make *something* in the database change. As has been suggested, a timestamp column would fit the bill. Alternatively, you could use an incrementing counter column, if that would provide you more useful information later.